# Repainting widgets in QT

Tags: c++, qt

I have a piece of code that initializes an instance of a QWidget, puts it inside a layout and invokes the animation. All of that is happening in the loop. I've encountered a problem of each iteration drawing the animation at the same time, completely ignoring QThread::usleep(). Is there a way to clean the layout the proper way so that I could achieve desired result?

```
double randomTestArray[numOfPoints];
double fMin = 0;
double fMax = 20;
srand(time(NULL));
for(int p = 0 ; p < 100 ; p++)
{
    Equalizer * eq = new Equalizer();
    ui->verticalLayout->addWidget(eq);
    for(int i = 0 ; i < numOfPoints ; i++)
    {
        randomTestArray[i] = fMin + (double)rand() * (fMax - fMin) / RAND_MAX;
    }             
    eq->setChunk(&randomTestArray[0] , &startArray[0]);
    ui->verticalLayout->removeWidget(eq);
    delete eq;
    QThread::usleep(1000);
}
```

Animation is accomplished using QPropertyAnimation and paintEvent() in setChunk() method. Notify me if you're going to need any more code.

Adding breakdown of Equalizer class :

```
void Equalizer::setChunk(double *chunk, int * startYArr)
{

if(*startYArr == -1)
{
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 24 ; i++)
    {
        *(startYArr + i) = 150;
    }
}

int xCoordinateArray[24];
int yCoordinateArray[24];

for(int i = 0 ; i < 24 ; i++)
{
    yCoordinateArray[i] = *(chunk + i) * 5;
    xCoordinateArray[i] = 100 + i*25;
}

cout << "Chunk initialized" << endl;
cout << "Start Coordinates : " << endl;
for(int i = 0 ; i < 24 ; i++)
{
    cout << startYArr[i] << endl;
}
cout << "End Coordinates : " << endl;

for(int i = 0 ; i < 24 ; i++)
{
    cout << yCoordinateArray[i] << endl;
}

QPropertyAnimation *animation = new QPropertyAnimation(this , "nrect");
animation->setDuration(2000);
animation->setStartValue(QRect(xCoordinateArray[0] , *(startYArr + 0) , 10 , 10));
animation->setEndValue(QRect(xCoordinateArray[0] , 150 - yCoordinateArray[0] , 10 , 10));
animation->start();
connect(animation, &QPropertyAnimation::valueChanged , [=](){update();});

QPropertyAnimation *animation2 = new QPropertyAnimation(this , "nrect2");
animation2->setDuration(2000);
animation2->setStartValue(QRect(xCoordinateArray[1] , *(startYArr + 1), 10 , 10));
animation2->setEndValue(QRect(xCoordinateArray[1] ,  150 - yCoordinateArray[1] , 10 , 10));
animation2->start();
connect(animation2, &QPropertyAnimation::valueChanged , [=](){update();});

QPropertyAnimation *animation3 = new QPropertyAnimation(this , "nrect3");
animation3->setDuration(2000);
animation3->setStartValue(QRect(xCoordinateArray[2] , *(startYArr +2) , 10 , 10));
animation3->setEndValue(QRect(xCoordinateArray[2] ,  150 - yCoordinateArray[2] , 10 , 10));
animation3->start();
connect(animation3, &QPropertyAnimation::valueChanged , [=](){update();});
................................
 for(int i = 0; i < 24 ; i++)
{
    *(startYArr + i) = yCoordinateArray[i];
}


void Equalizer::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
Q_UNUSED(event);

QRect ellipse(mRect);
QPainter painter(this);
painter.setBrush(Qt::red);
painter.drawEllipse(ellipse);

QRect ellipse2(mRect2);
painter.setBrush(Qt::red);
painter.drawEllipse(ellipse2);

QRect ellipse3(mRect3);
painter.setBrush(Qt::red);
painter.drawEllipse(ellipse3);
.............................
```

Attempted solution :

```
eq->setChunk(&randomTestArray[0] , &startArray[0]);
QCoreApplication::processEvents();
ui->verticalLayout->removeWidget(eq);
QThread::usleep(1000);
```

Comment: "for(int p = 0 ; p < 1 ; p++)" -- really?  Also, you appear to create an `Equalizer` instance, add it to a layout, call `setChunk` on it, remove it from the layout and delete it all without ever having returned to the `Qt` event loop.  I think you'll need to provide a [MCVE].

Comment: What do you mean "returning to the Qt event loop"?

Comment: `Qt` is event based.  When you call functions against instances of `QObject` derived classes it will, generally, result in one or more events being posted to those objects.  In order for those events to be processed the event loop needs to be allowed to run.

Comment: Can you provide a solution based on this code?

Comment: I can't provide an answer because it's unclear what the code is supposed to do.  As requested in an earlier comment please provide a [MCVE].

Comment: I do realize that it's awfully programmed now, but I simply have to make it work at first. Tell me please if this additional code would suffice.

Answer (score 2):

Normally Qt uses its event system (triggered by [`QWidget::update`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#update)) to periodically update the screen to avoid too much [painting operations](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#paintEvent). Because you want to update the screen inside a `for`-loop without returning to the main event loop, the default approach doesn't work. Different solutions are possible:

1. *Processing the events manually*: You should call [`QCoreApplication::processEvents`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents-1) repetitively during the whole wait time instead of `QThread::usleep` to process all the new events (coming from `QPropertyAnimation`). Note that you probably want to process the events, before removing and destructing your `Equalizer` object.
2. <strike>*Force to repaint the screen immediately*:</strike> You can force Qt to repaint the screen immediately by calling [`QWidget::repaint`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#repaint), which will invoke the `paintEvent` immediately.
   *This option will not work well in combination with `QPropertyAnimation`.*
3. *Use timer events to update periodically*: Remove the `for`-loop (and `usleep` function call) and use a [`QTimer`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html) object to periodically perform some actions.

Note that option 3 is the preferred solution to use with an event based system, such as Qt.

Comment: I've tried all of these approaches, but it still starts painting only after the loop. I've added it at the end of the question

Comment: Option 3 does not contain a `for` loop anymore. So, it is impossible that the animation starts after the event loop.

Comment: I overlooked the fact that you were using `QPropertyAnimation`, therefore, I updated my first approach. Note that option 3 is my preferred solution.